# VB6: Is this Sub ever reached?

Tags: vb6

I am rewriting some VB6 legacy programs and ran across the following code (variable names changed for security)...

```
  Dim blnValue1 As Boolean
  Dim strForValue As String

  sqlQuery = "SELECT a.* FROM databaseName a " & _
                  "WHERE a.ssn = '" & strInput1 & "'" & _
                  " and a.column2 = '" & strInput2 & "'"

  Set rsInsert = New ADODB.Recordset
  rsInsert.Open sqlQuery, Connection

  blnValue1 = False
  Do Until rsInsert.EOF
    strForValue = Trim(rsInsert("value"))

    If strForValue <> "1234" Then
      [some unimportant code here]
    End If

    blnValue1 = True
    rsInsert.MoveNext
  Loop

  If blnValue1 = False Then
    InsertValue
  End If
```

I know this is probably really obvious but I want to make sure: the Sub "InsertValue" would never be called in this code right? I mean the bool is set to true while the Recordset is reading. Is there a VB6 or Recordset specific rule I am unaware of that would make "blnValue1" false at some point?

I can't run the old VB6 code to check if it reaches the "InsertValue" Sub because it accesses production files that I don't want to mess with until a have a perfect handle on everything the code is doing.

Comment: Gah! The SQL Injection hole, it burns us!

Comment: Sure it can. All it will take is the rsInsert recordset to have no records in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first instinct was that it **would** be possible to call the `InsertValue` function if the sql query did not return any results. Regardless of what actually happens, I believe this is the author's intent.

On further reflection, though, I had a vague suspicion about an issue where `EOF` is not set for a RecordSet before the first call to `MoveNext` — similar to how file streams don't set it until after you try to read past the end of the file — so I went to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821459.aspx). Reading this, it looks like `EOF` **is** set to `True` if there are no results:

> If you open a Recordset object containing no records, the BOF and EOF properties are set to True, and the Recordset object's RecordCount property setting is 0.

Therefore, my initial instinct is confirmed. **The `InsertValue` method will be called in the case where the query does not return any results.**

While you are working with this code, you should fix that nasty sql injection vulnerability.